# OpenMP Dot Product and Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, openmp, reduction

I'm trying to implement dotproduct in OpenMP with large arrays allocated with malloc. However, when I use reduction(+:result) it produces different results for each program run. Why do I get different results? How can I remedy that? And how can this example be optimized? Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>

const int N = 1e1;

int main ()
{
  int    i, nthreads, tid;
  double x_seq, x_par, *y, *z, cpu_time_used;
  clock_t start, end;

  y = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);
  z = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*N);

  for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
      y[i] = i * 1.0;
      z[i] = i * 2.0;
  }

  x_seq = 0;
  x_par = 0;
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) x_seq += y[i] * z[i];

  #pragma omp parallel shared(y, z) private(i, tid)
  {
      #pragma omp single
      {
          nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
      }
      tid = omp_get_thread_num();

      #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:x_par)
      for (i=tid; i<N; i+=nthreads)
      {
          x_par += y[i] * z[i];
      }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you are using. (I assume this is C?) Also, note that if this is C (not C++), then [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3488231).

Comment: To answer your question `how can this example be optimized?` the answer is that [it's memory bandwidth bound so it won't scale with the number of threads though that does not mean multiple threads won't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179738/measuring-memory-bandwidth-from-the-dot-product-of-two-arrays).

Comment: @ace, this is valid C/C++ code but not casting will make it invalid C++ code. Do you have anything useful to say about this question?

Comment: @Zboson Check the revision history. The first revision did not tag the language, so I asked the OP to tag it accordingly. And since I noticed that OP was using `<stdlib.h>` and not `<cstdlib>`, I guessed it was C and not C++, so I added that it should not be casted if this is C. Please explain more if you still think what I did was wrong. Also, now that it *is* tagged as C, it makes my previous comment even more useful.

Comment: @ace casting or not casting is a matter of opinion it's not something that is right or wrong.

Comment: @Zboson So is writing unreadable code, or `using namespace std`, or numerous other bad programming practice. They may not be wrong, but they are bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's several things wrong here.

Let's look at the loop as it stands:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(y, z) private(i, tid)
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  }
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();

  #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:x_par)
  for (i=tid; i<N; i+=nthreads)
  {
      x_par += y[i] * z[i];
  }
}
```

So (1) notice that you (presumably) want `x_par` to be accessible outside of this region.  So you'll want the `reduction(+:x_par)` on the outer section, not the inner.  If you also add the very helpful `default(none)` clause, you'll also find that there's no clause describing the sharing of `nthreads`; let's explicitly make that shared.

So let's look again:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(y, z, nthreads) private(i, tid) reduction(+:x_par) default(none)
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  }
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();

  #pragma omp parallel for 
  for (i=tid; i<N; i+=nthreads)
  {
      x_par += y[i] * z[i];
  }
}
```

So looking more carefully, we now see that you have two `omp parallel` sections.  That means, if nested parallelism is enabled, that you'll have `nthreads` tasks each launching `nthreads` taks to do that loop; so the loop would end up with nthreads times the right answer if everything worked.  So let's get rid of the parallel, just using the for:

```
 #pragma omp parallel shared(y, z, nthreads) private(i, tid) reduction(+:x_par) default(none)
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  }
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();

  #pragma omp for 
  for (i=tid; i<N; i+=nthreads)
  {
      x_par += y[i] * z[i];
  }
}
```

So that has the sharing correct and isn't nesting parallelism, but it still doesn't give the right answer; it gives a much smaller result.  What's wrong?  Let's take a look at the for loop.  Each thread wants to start at tid and skip nthreads, fine; but why do we want the `omp for` there?

Let's take a look at a simpler version which works:

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(y, z) reduction(+:x_par) default(none)
{
  #pragma omp for
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
      x_par += y[i] * z[i];
  }
}
```

Note that here we aren't decomposing the loop explicitly with tid and nthreads - we don't have to, because `omp for` decomposes the loop for us; it assigns loop iterations to threads.

So looking back at what we have, we have a manual decomposition of the loop - which is fine, sometimes that's what you need to do; *and* an `omp for` which tries to take that loop and split it up amongst threads.  But we're already doing that; the `omp for` simply makes us skip iterations here!

So getting rid of the `omp for`

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(y, z, nthreads) private(i, tid) reduction(+:x_par) default(none)
{
  #pragma omp single
  {
      nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
  }
  tid = omp_get_thread_num();

  for (i=tid; i<N; i+=nthreads)
  {
      x_par += y[i] * z[i];
  }
}
```

Gets us the right answer.