# GCC auto-vectorization has no effect on runtime, even when supposedly "profitable"

Tags: c, gcc, auto-vectorization

I've spent the past few days reading about autovectorization with gcc 4.7. I followed some examples I saw online, and the setup seems to be correct. But when I actually run with the code and compare between  vectorization on or off, there isn't a noticeable difference in runtime.

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    long b = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 0); 
    unsigned long long int i;
    unsigned long long int n = (int)pow(2,29);                                                                                                                                                                                            
    float total = 0;

    float *__restrict__ x1; 
    float *__restrict__ y1; 

    posix_memalign((void *)&x1, 16, sizeof(float)*n);
    posix_memalign((void *)&y1, 16, sizeof(float)*n);


    float *__restrict__ x = __builtin_assume_aligned(x1,16);
    float *__restrict__ y = __builtin_assume_aligned(y1,16);

    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
            x[i] = i;
            y[i] = i;
    }   

    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            y[i] += x[i];
    }   

    printf("y[%li]: \t\t\t\t%f\n",  b,y[b]);
    printf("correct answer: \t\t\t%f\n", (b)*2);
    return 0;
}
```

Some of this stuff seems redundant to me, but was necessary to get the compiler to understand what was going on (especially the fact that the data were aligned). The "b" variable that's read from command line is just there because I was paranoid about the compiler optimizing away the loop entirely.

Here is the compiler command when vectorizeration is enabled:

```
gcc47 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=3 -msse2 -lm -O2 -finline-functions -funswitch-loops -fpredictive-commoning -fgcse-after-reload -fipa-cp-clone test.c -ftree-vectorize -o v
```

Basically, this is equivalent to just using -O3. I put the flags in myself so that all I needed to do was remove "ftree-vectorize" and be able to test the result sans vectorization.

Here is the output of the ftree-vectorize-verbose flag, to show that the code is in fact being vectorized:

```
Analyzing loop at test.c:29

29: vect_model_load_cost: aligned.
29: vect_model_load_cost: inside_cost = 1, outside_cost = 0 .
29: vect_model_load_cost: aligned.
29: vect_model_load_cost: inside_cost = 1, outside_cost = 0 .
29: vect_model_simple_cost: inside_cost = 1, outside_cost = 0 .
29: vect_model_store_cost: aligned.
29: vect_model_store_cost: inside_cost = 1, outside_cost = 0 .
29: cost model: Adding cost of checks for loop versioning aliasing.

29: Cost model analysis: 
  Vector inside of loop cost: 4
  Vector outside of loop cost: 4
  Scalar iteration cost: 4
  Scalar outside cost: 1
  prologue iterations: 0
  epilogue iterations: 0
  Calculated minimum iters for profitability: 2

29:   Profitability threshold = 3


Vectorizing loop at test.c:29

29: Profitability threshold is 3 loop iterations.
29: created 1 versioning for alias checks.

29: LOOP VECTORIZED.
Analyzing loop at test.c:24

24: vect_model_induction_cost: inside_cost = 2, outside_cost = 2 .
24: vect_model_simple_cost: inside_cost = 2, outside_cost = 0 .
24: not vectorized: relevant stmt not supported: D.5806_18 = (float) D.5823_58;

test.c:7: note: vectorized 1 loops in function.
```

Note that the vectorization is profitable after 3 iterations, and I'm running with 2^29~=500,000,000 iterations. So I should expect a vastly different runtime with vectorization turned off, right?

Well, here are the runtimes of the code (I ran it 20 times in a row):

```
59.082s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
79.385s
57.557s
57.264s
53.588s
54.300s
53.645s
69.044s
57.238s
59.366s
56.314s
55.224s
57.308s
57.682s
56.083s
369.590s
59.963s
55.683s
54.979s
62.309s
```

Throwing away that weird ~370s outlier, that gives a mean runtime of 58.7s, with a standard deviation of 6.0s.

Next, I'll compile with the same command as before, but with no -ftree-vectorize flag:

```
gcc47 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=3 -msse2 -lm -O2 -finline-functions -funswitch-loops -fpredictive-commoning -fgcse-after-reload -fipa-cp-clone test.c -o nov
```

Again running the program 20 times in a row yields the following times:

```
69.471s                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
57.134s
56.240s
57.040s
55.787s
56.530s
60.010s
60.187s
324.227s
56.377s
55.337s
54.110s
56.164s
59.919s
493.468s
63.876s
57.389s
55.553s
54.908s
56.828s
```

Again throwing away outliers, this gives a mean runtimee of 57.9s with a standard deviation of 3.6s.

So these two versions have statistically indistinguishable runtimes.

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong? Does the "profitability threshold" spit out by the compiler not mean what I think it means? I really appreciate any help people can give me, I've been trying to figure this out for the past week.

**EDIT**:

I implemented the change that @nilspipenbrinck suggested, and it seems to have worked. I stuck the vectorized loop in a function, and called that function a boatload of times. The relative run-times are now 24.0s (sigma of <0.1s) for no vectorization vs 20.8s (sigma of <0.2s) for vectorization, or a 13% speed improvement. Not as much as I was hoping for, but at least now I know its working! Thanks for taking the time to look at my question and write an answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to make tests on outdated compiler version? What is your hardware?

Comment: Locality of reference is a big deal on modern processors.  Your program doesn't have any, its runtime is completely dominated by the cost of accessing RAM.

Comment: @Drop I'm planning on getting this working on a bunch of different computers in my lab, and they all use this compiler. Actually, they version they use is older than this, gcc4.4 or lower. But some of the functions I wanted to experiment with didnt come around until 4.7. I don't have the ability to upgrade the compilers, or I would.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the advice, I'm looking up information on locality of reference now.

Comment: This is a duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159455/why-vectorizing-the-loop-does-not-have-performance-improvement/18159503#18159503

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't do much arithmetic. Therefore the runtime of your test code is memory bound. E.g. you spend most of the time by moving the data between the CPU and memory.

Furthermore your n is very large with 2^29 elements. Therefore you don't benefit from the first and second level cache in any way.

If you want to see improvements with SSE, use a smaller n such that you only touch 8 or 16 kilobyte of data. Also make sure that the data is 'hot' e.g. it has recently been accessed by the CPU. That way the data does not have to be moved from main memory but it gets moved from the caches which is several magnitudes faster.

As an alternative you could also do  a *lot* more arithmetic. This would give the memory prefetch system a chance to fetch the data from main memory in the background while you utilize the CPU doing math.

Summarized: If the arithmetic is faster than your system can move the memory around you will not see any benefits. Memory access times will be the bottleneck and the few cycles you save using the SSE instruction set will get lost in the noise of memory access timings.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Operating on 8 kilobytes of data won't really have a measurable runtime, but I could stick that vectorized loop in a function and then call that function a million times. Thanks for the advice, I'm going to go try that right now.

Comment: @user2635263 The runtime can be measured. Just use the cycle counter that you can read out via the RDTSC instruction. Google for it and you'll find benchmark frameworks.

Comment: Although it's correct to say this is memory bandwidth bound that does not mean it can't be improved significantly. If the OP uses multiple threads and non-temporal stores he/she would likely on order a factor two improvement.

Answer (score 2):

There are several factors that determine how profitable will be to vectorize code. In this case (basing this on the output you provided) the compiler is only vectorizing one loop, I would think that's the second one because the first one would be typically ignored since there is not enough computation being done for it to be profitable to vectorize.

The running times you are posting are for the whole code, not for the loop alone, so there is only so much vectorizing will do for the overall running time. If you really want to see how much improvement is there from vectorization I would suggest running a profiler such as AMD Code XL, Intel Vtune, OProfile and such, it will tell you specifically for that loop how much improvement in terms of time and performance you are making.

Right now I'm working in evaluation of vectorizing compilers, and I would code running upt to 60 times faster with vectorization, other times the speedup is not as impressive, and it all depends on the loop, the compiler and the architecture you are using.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the answer. I've learned a lot about code vectorization since posting this!